# How to log out of my old git account in the comand line for mac

Tags: git, shell, github, command-line, terminal

I deleted my old github account last year when I gave up trying to learn how to use it. I'm picking it up again now but it shows my username as the one I used for my old account, which doesn't exist anymore. Every answer I've seen on here uses bash and when I updated to Catalina my terminal updated to zsh.

I already tried deleting my logging info from keychain access but the terminal still shows my old account info. How do I update my github user info on the terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The infos are probably stored in your ~/.gitconfig file.
When you open the terminal, type

```
cat ~/.gitconfig
```

If you see the infos you mentioned, you can either edit the file, or if you want to restart from the beginning, just remove the file:

```
rm ~/.gitconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

The following command will remove your credentials from the system:

```
git config --unset-all user.name
git config --unset-all user.email
```

If the credentials are set locally for a repository, you need to `cd` into that directory first.

If you want to remove the connection to github for and existing repository, find out the remote name with:

```
git remote -v
```

It will likely be called `origin`. You can remove it with:

```
git remote remove origin
```